# Slim 3 - replacement for isPost()?

Tags: slim, php-5.6, slim-3, psr-7

In Slim 2, I would do this,

```
$app->map('/login', function () use ($app) {

    // Test for Post & make a cheap security check, to get avoid from bots
    if ($app->request()->isPost() && sizeof($app->request()->post()) >= 2) {

        //
    }

    // render login
    $app->render('login.twig');

})->via('GET','POST')->setName('login');
```

But in Slim 3,

```
// Post the login form.
$app->post('/login', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {

    // Get all post parameters:
    $allPostPutVars = $request->getParsedBody();

    // Test for Post & make a cheap security check, to get avoid from bots
    if ($request()->isPost() && sizeof($allPostPutVars) >= 2) {

        ///
    }

});
```

I get this error,

> Fatal error: Function name must be a string in C:...

Obviously that `isPost()` is deprecated, so what should I use instead in Slim 3 for isPost's replacement?

Comment: I think `$request()->isPost()` should be just `$request->isPost()`, without the parathesis, in your second code sample. `$request` is an object.

Comment: Also, the method `isPost` is still available according to the docs: http://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/request.html#the-request-method

Comment: got it. thanks guys.

Comment: If you do `$app->post(…)` every request to this is post, a get request would not be mapped to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/request.html#the-request-method) and [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33330573/slim-3-replacement-for-ispost#comment54459488_33330573), Slim supports these proprietary methods:

- $request->isGet()
- $request->isPost()
- $request->isPut()
- $request->isDelete()
- $request->isHead()
- $request->isPatch()
- $request->isOptions()

Here it is an example of usage:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;

$app = new \Slim\App;
$app->map(['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'HEAD', 'PATCH', 'OPTIONS'], '/', function (ServerRequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response) {
    echo "isGet():" . $request->isGet() . "<br/>";
    echo "isPost():" . $request->isPost() . "<br/>";
    echo "isPut():" . $request->isPut() . "<br/>";
    echo "isDelete():" . $request->isDelete() . "<br/>";
    echo "isHead():" . $request->isHead() . "<br/>";
    echo "isPatch():" . $request->isPatch() . "<br/>";
    echo "isOptions():" . $request->isOptions() . "<br/>";

    return $response;
});

$app->run();
```

Comment: Thanks for the detail answer! :D

Answer (score 2):

In Slim 4, there's no such helper and so the syntax gets longer (like a lot of Slim 4 stuff):

```php
$request->getMethod() === 'POST'
```